# Не правильно запускается программа вопрос по реестру Windows?

Tags: реестр, vnc

Зарегистрировал свой протокол в реестре.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc]
@="URL:VNC Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\RealVNC\\VNC Viewer\\vncviewer.exe" %1"
```

Но запускается программа не правильно. Запускаю ее так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге получаю ошибку следующего вида. Она слово vnc считает за адрес, а все 
остольное за порт. Как мне убрать слово vnc в начале?

Comment: Протокол регистрируется в protocols... тут другое, скорее всего вам нужно убрать двоеточие, вместо двоеточия пробел. Но это не протокол, вы путаете с протоколом, это командная строка.

Comment: @nick-n-a Пишет, что приложение не найдено

Comment: Само проще - добавьте путь в path. Или создайте ссылку через батник. Или... это пишется в какой-то другой ветке.